# Changing the default dispatcher configuration for all actors in an Akka ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka, actor, dispatcher

Is there way to change the default dispatchers config values for all actors in an Actor system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the settings for default dispatcher in your application.conf. The available settings are in https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf (Line 253 onwards).